# Iterating over groovy file contents

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two groovy scipts (executed in Jenkins pipeline), one with variables:

```
// Params file
PARAM1 = "1"
PARAM2 = "2"
PARAM3 = "3"
PARAM4 = "4"

return this
```

and the second one that loads this file and uses the params:

```
def load_params() {
    def parameters = load "params.groovy"
        final_parameter = ""
    
        for (parameter in parameters) {
            if(final_parameter == "") {
                final_parameter = parameter.key.toUpperCase() + "=" + parameter.value
            } else {
                final_parameter = final_parameter+ "&|&" + parameter.key.toUpperCase() + "=" + parameter.value
            }
        }
    
        return final_parameter
    }
    
    return this
```

Issue is that doing the iteration over parameters is not working. The type is not a map so I cannot access variables like that.

I would use parameters.PARAM1 to handle it, but the first script is dynamic and names change so there is a need to do it without hard defining the name.

**Is there any way to change/iterate the parameters to get the "key" and "values"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you can do.

**Option 01: Make the Parameters a Map**

This is the best solution I guess.

```
// Params file
parameters = [ "PARAM1": "1", "PARAM2": "2", "PARAM3": "3", "PARAM4": "4"]

return this
```

**Option 02 : Read the Parameters as a file**

Instead of loading as a Script, you can read the Params as a File, then iterate over it line-by-line and read the parameters.

**Option 03: Get all the Variables defined in the current binding.**

This will probably return all the variables in the current Binding, so you may have to filter out the ones you defined in the param file.

```
def load_params() {
    def parameters = load "params.groovy"
        final_parameter = ""
        paramMap = [:] << parameters.getBinding().getVariables()
        for (parameter in paramMap) {
            if(final_parameter == "") {
                final_parameter = parameter.key.toUpperCase() + "=" + parameter.value
            } else {
                final_parameter = final_parameter+ "&|&" + parameter.key.toUpperCase() + "=" + parameter.value
            }
        }
    
        return final_parameter
    }
    
    return this
```

Comment: Great! Option 1 worked like a charm, then just iterating over parameters.parameters got me what I needed!

Thanks a lot!